# In django, I can't understand how include function works

Tags: django

I just started learning Django. I can't understand how include function knows what is polls.urls.

I don't import polls.urls but it works!

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: It makes use fo the `importlib` to import that module itself.

Comment: since you have added your app name (polls) in INSTALLLED_APPS, Django can fetch the URLs by ```polls.urls``` without importing the apps

Answer (score 0):

It makes use of the [**`importlib`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to import a module with the given name.

Indeed, we can inspect the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/urls/conf.py#L12-L54), and we see how it is basically some logic wrapped around the importlib:

> ```
> from importlib import import_module
> …
> def include(arg, namespace=None):
> # …
> if isinstance(urlconf_module, str):
> urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
> patterns = getattr(urlconf_module, 'urlpatterns', urlconf_module)
> app_name = getattr(urlconf_module, 'app_name', app_name)
> # …
> return (urlconf_module, app_name, namespace)
> ```

It thus will first do some preprocessing where for a 2-tuple it will unpack it into an `urconf_module` and a `app_name`, and then uses the [**`import_module(…)`** function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to import the module with the given qualified name.

Then some post-processing is done where it will aim to obtain the `'urlpatterns` and the `app_name` from that module, and eventually return a 3-tuple with the module, the `app_name` and the `namespace`.

Comment: I got it! I really appreciate it!!